# Spring Config cannot detect uri to fetch all values from yml file in Windows

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a problem about fetching all values from yml file located under config-server-repository folder in Windows as uri cannot be detected.

I added yml file to git through all these commands following below.

```
1 ) git init
2 ) git add.
3 ) git commit -m "Initial Commit"
```

How can I fix that.

Here is my bootstrap file shown below.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:C:\Users\MyUsername\IdeaProjects\microservices-demo\config-server-repository
          clone-on-start: true
    fail-fast: true # cannot reach the config server to load the configuration and stop it.
```

Comment: Either use double \ or use / in the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I revised the path, the issue disappeared.

Here is the answer shown below.

```
uri: file:///C:/Users/MyUsername/IdeaProjects/microservices-demo/config-server-repository
```